# Changing power of an audio signal to a specific dB

Tags: power-spectral-density

Suppose I have an audio signal with power 31dB. I want to change the signal power to 24dB. How can I change the power of that signal from 31dB to 24dB?

Comment: Hm, do you understand decibel (dB)?

Comment: use some resistors so some power is consumed in one and remaing is deliverd to the load. you have to reduce power by a factor of 5